# Is it possible to mark designated entries in a bibliography with an asterisk?

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex` to produce a bibliography with several sections like this:

```
\defbibheading{cvpubs}[List of Publications]{\section{#1}}
\defbibheading{subbibliography}{\noindent\bfseries\itshape{#1}}
\printbibheading[heading=cvpubs]

\printbibliography[env=nolabel,sorting=ydnt,keyword=peer,heading=subbibliography,title={Peer-reviewed articles}]
\printbibliography[env=nolabel,sorting=ydnt,keyword=chapter,heading=subbibliography,title={Book chapters}]

% and so on ...
```

Now I need to mark certain entries with an asterisk left of the entry. Something like this:

* Besserwisser, John (2007). "Whatever you say, you're wrong". In: Journal for Know-it-alls. (1)1. pp. 1-19.

Is this possible?

P.S. If you are wondering why anyone would want to do such a thing: In my case it is simply demanded by a funding agency to mark certain publication in my publication list with an asterisk. But you could also use this to mark the mandatory readings or the recommended readings or so in a reading list.

Comment: Where are the special entries specified: in the bib file, or the TeX file?

Comment: @mafp: it doesn't really matter. bib file is probably easier.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is a way to do it by adding a new field `asterisk` to the entries in the `bib` file.  The solution requires `biber`.

```
\begin{filecontents}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{asterisk}
\end{filecontents}
```

The code above is to extend the data model with the new field `asterisk`.

```
\renewbibmacro{begentry}{%
  \iffieldundef{asterisk}
    {}
    {*\addspace}%
}
```

EDIT A somehow simpler method is to create a new category for entries to be marked with an asterisk

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{asterisk}
```

then add the entires to be marked to such a category

```
\addtocategory{asterisk}{key1,key2, ...}
```

where `key1`, `key2`, ... are `bib` keys for the entries to be marked and finally

```
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\ifcategory{asterisk}{*\addspace}{}}
```

Comment: Hm, that looks surprisingly simple. But I'm not sure I understand where the code goes. Is it in biblatex-dm.cfg? And the second bit in the preamble?

Comment: Oh, and what value do I assign to the new field? asterisk = {true}?

Comment: @Christoph you can use you can use the `filecontents` package. In this way you create the biblatex configuraation file on the fly. Then the two snippets above in the preamble of your document. Any value should do for the new field.

Comment: I thought I'd ask you this before posting another question — You helped me out earlier with [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113136/4071) (see comments) in adding an asterisk to the citation number based on a keyword. Do you have thoughts on extending it for two keywords? For instance, if keyword `A` then `[1]*`, if `B` then `[1]†` or if `A, B` then `[1]*†` or something like that. Adding another definition for `renewbibmacro` doesn't seem to be an option, since it replaces the previous ones...

Comment: @yoda You can use `\ifkeyword{A}{*}{}\ifkeyword{B}{$\dagger$}{}`, or you can nest one `\ifkeyword` inside another, `\ifkeyword{A}{\ifkeyword{B}{*$\dagger$}{*}}{\ifkeyword{B}{$\dagger$}{}}`.

Comment: Dang! Now I'm embarassed I didn't think of a simple `if`... Thanks :)