# Including an asterisk in a reference item number

Tags: biblatex, biber

How do I add a mark (asterisk/dagger) to a particular bib entry, based on a keyword? For example consider the bib file:

```
@article{Doe2012a,
    author  = {J. Doe},
    title   = {Lorem Ipsum -- Part I},
    journal = {J. Dolor Sit Am.},
    volume  = {1},
    pages   = {1--10},
    month   = {1},
    year    = {2012},
    keywords = {invited},
}

@article{Doe2012b,
    author  = {J. Doe},
    title   = {Lorem Ipsum -- Part II},
    journal = {J. Dolor Sit Am.},
    volume  = {2},
    pages   = {11--20},
    month   = {2},
    year    = {2012},
}
```

and the tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=nty, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{path/to/bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=Articles, prefixnumbers=A., type=article]
\end{document}
```

which will produce an output like:

```
[A.1] J. Doe, "Lorem Ipsum ...
[A.2] J. Doe, "Lorem Ipsum ...
```

Now how can I design a filter or otherwise, that will look for the presence of `invited` in a keyword and then produce an output like

```
[A.1]* J. Doe, "Lorem Ipsum ...
[A.2] J. Doe, "Lorem Ipsum ...
```

where there is now an asterisk next to the ref item number? This way I can easily place a footnote to indicate which references were invited articles.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103862/16895. If you want to use a keyword use `\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\ifkeyword{invited}{*\addspace}{}}`

Comment: @Guido Thanks, and what should I do to place the asterisk on the citation number (as in my example above) instead of before the text?

Comment: or perhaps mark those citation numbers in a different color...

Comment: A possibility would be `\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\ifkeyword{invited}{\hspace{-\biblabelsep}\makebox[\biblabelsep][l]{*}}{}}` or one has to define how labels are printed (including the same if conditions redefining) `\defbibenvironment`.