# Functionality of apacites \nocitemeta with biblatex-apa: adding asterisks to author lastnames (meta-analysis)

Tags: biblatex, apa6

I am using the `apa6` class to write a meta-analysis. For bibliography I am using `biblatex-apa`. I want to mark all references with an asterisk (`*`) that are primary studies. The asterisk is to be in front of the lastname of the first author. My first attempt was adding the asterisks to the bibtex entries for author. This failed miserably, as the asterisks appear in the text as well :/

I found that the `apacite` package has a convenient `\nocitemeta` command, that just adds the asterisks in the Reference list. I do not want to switch to `apacite` as `biblatex-apa` is working fine otherwise. Is there an easy work-around in `biblatex`?

Comment: See also [Is it possible to mark designated entries in a bibliography with an asterisk?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103854/35864)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could add the following to your preamble

```
\newtoggle{bib@asterisk}
\DeclareEntryOption{asterisk}[true]{\settoggle{bib@asterisk}{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \iftoggle{bib@asterisk}%
    {*}%
    {}%
}
```

This allows you to set an option `asterisk` on a per-type basis in the `.bib` file. If this option is set, an asterisk will be printed before the entry in the bibliography.

Use it like so

```
@book{uthor,
  author        = {Uthor, Arnold},
  title         = {A Book},
  date          = {2013},
  location      = {Place},
  publisher     = {P. Ublisher's \& Co.},
  options       = {asterisk},
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{bohec,
  author        = {Le Bohec, Yann},
  title         = {Histoire militaire des guerres puniques},
  date          = {1996},
  location      = {Monaco},
  publisher     = {Rocher},
  isbn          = {2-268-02147-5},
  options       = {asterisk},
}
@book{uthor,
  author        = {Uthor, Arnold},
  title         = {A Book},
  date          = {2013},
  location      = {Place},
  publisher     = {P. Ublisher's \& Co.},
  options       = {asterisk},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newtoggle{bib@asterisk}
\DeclareEntryOption{asterisk}[true]{\settoggle{bib@asterisk}{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \iftoggle{bib@asterisk}%
    {*}%
    {}%
}

\begin{document}
  \cite{wilde,cicero,coleridge,vangennep,bohec,uthor}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

If you prefer a more on-the-fly solution, try this.

We declare a new bibliography category `asterisk`.

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{asterisk}
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \ifcategory{asterisk}%
    {*}%
    {}%
}
```

We can then use `\addtocategory{asterisk}{uthor,bohec}` in the document.

This will *not* print the entries in question, just mark them as requiring a star should they be printed.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{bohec,
  author        = {Le Bohec, Yann},
  title         = {Histoire militaire des guerres puniques},
  date          = {1996},
  location      = {Monaco},
  publisher     = {Rocher},
  isbn          = {2-268-02147-5},
}
@book{uthor,
  author        = {Uthor, Arnold},
  title         = {A Book},
  date          = {2013},
  location      = {Place},
  publisher     = {P. Ublisher's \& Co.},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{asterisk}
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \ifcategory{asterisk}%
    {*}%
    {}%
}

\begin{document}
  \addtocategory{asterisk}{uthor,bohec}
  \cite{wilde,cicero,coleridge,vangennep,bohec,uthor}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Both MWEs yield
[image]

---

Using the second method,

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{asterisk}
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \ifcategory{asterisk}%
    {*}%
    {}%
}
```

we can even define `\nocitemeta` via

```
\newcommand*{\nocitemeta}[1]{%
  \nocite{#1}%
  \addtocategory{asterisk}{#1}%
}
```

We can the use this command analogous to APAcite's `\nocitemeta`.
Note that with this `\nocitemeta` even entries that were cited before get an asterisk if you perform a `\nocitemeta` on them.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{bohec,
  author        = {Le Bohec, Yann},
  title         = {Histoire militaire des guerres puniques},
  date          = {1996},
  location      = {Monaco},
  publisher     = {Rocher},
  isbn          = {2-268-02147-5},
}
@book{uthor,
  author        = {Uthor, Arnold},
  title         = {A Book},
  date          = {2013},
  location      = {Place},
  publisher     = {P. Ublisher's \& Co.},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{asterisk}
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \ifcategory{asterisk}%
    {*}%
    {}%
}

\newcommand*{\nocitemeta}[1]{%
  \nocite{#1}%
  \addtocategory{asterisk}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
  \nocitemeta{bohec,uthor}
  \cite{wilde,cicero,coleridge,vangennep,bohec}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your answer was very useful to me :) I liked the second solution a bit better, as the asterisked references might not be asterisked in the next paper one writes.