# It there a way to make URL link in bibliography as one word `Link`?

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

This is my code:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes }
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes }
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes }
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@techreport{NBERw10828,
 title = "Accounting for Cross-Country Income Differences",
 author = "Francesco Caselli",
 institution = "National Bureau of Economic Research",
 type = "Working Paper",
 series = "Working Paper Series",
 number = "10828",
 year = "2004",
 month = "October",
 URL = "http://www.nber.org/papers/w10828",
 abstract = {Why are some countries so much richer than others? Development Accounting is a first-pass attempt at organizing the answer around two proximate determinants: factors of production and efficiency. It answers the question "how much of the cross-country income variance can be attributed to differences in (physical and human) capital, and how much to differences in the efficiency with which capital is used?" Hence, it does for the cross-section what growth accounting does in the time series. The current consensus is that efficiency is at least as important as capital in explaining income differences. I survey the data and the basic methods that lead to this consensus, and explore several extensions. I argue that some of these extensions may lead to a reconsideration of the evidence.},
}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks = true,
linkcolor = black,
anchorcolor = black,
citecolor = black,
urlcolor=blue,
bookmarksopen = true,
bookmarksnumbered = true,
bookmarksopenlevel = 2,
pdfstartview = {FitH},
pdfborder = {0 0 0}
}
\usepackage[indexing=cite,style=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear,sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\AtEveryCite{%
  \let\parentext=\parentexttrack%
  \let\bibopenparen=\bibopenbracket%
  \let\bibcloseparen=\bibclosebracket}
\makeatother
%\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
First \cite{NBERw10828}\par
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is what it gives:
[image]

This is what I want to have as a URL link, one short word `Link` which is underlined and blue:

[image]

How it can be done?

P.S.

BTW how can be star be added to citation if front `*Caselli`?

Comment: A serious disadvantage of printing only a "stub", rather than the actual URL, is that readers of hardcopy versions of your document will have a needlessly hard time tracking down the reference.

Comment: @Mico I agree, but it is what I was asked, and they want to do as it is...

Comment: Can you use the \href command in the bibtex file? Usually I see \url command, but maybe you can put \href{url}{Link}.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though it is not really advisable - in my opinion - you can use the redefinition

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\href{#1}{\underline{Link}}}
```

this definition will print the full URL if `hyperref` is not enabled

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{#1}{\underline{Link}}}
    {\url{#1}}}
```

Or maybe even - making use of the localisation capabilities `biblatex` offers

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  url = {link},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{#1}{\bibstring{url}}}
    {\url{#1}}}
```

For more options to customise the look of hyperlinks, see for example [How can I have colored and underlined links with hyperref?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26071/35864)

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{NBERw10828,
 title = "Accounting for Cross-Country Income Differences",
 author = "Francesco Caselli",
 institution = "National Bureau of Economic Research",
 type = "Working Paper",
 series = "Working Paper Series",
 number = "10828",
 year = "2004",
 month = "October",
 URL = "http://www.nber.org/papers/w10828",
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks = true,
linkcolor = black,
anchorcolor = black,
citecolor = black,
urlcolor=blue,
bookmarksopen = true,
bookmarksnumbered = true,
bookmarksopenlevel = 2,
pdfstartview = {FitH},
pdfborder = {0 0 0}
}
\usepackage[indexing=cite,style=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear,sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\AtEveryCite{%
  \let\parentext=\parentexttrack%
  \let\bibopenparen=\bibopenbracket%
  \let\bibcloseparen=\bibclosebracket}
\makeatother

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  url = {link},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{#1}{\bibstring{url}}}
    {\url{#1}}}

%\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
First \cite{NBERw10828}\par
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: BTW, do you how to make *in front of citation? `*Caselli...`

Comment: @saldenisov Try [Functionality of apacites \nocitemeta with biblatex-apa: adding asterisks to author lastnames (meta-analysis)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156706/35864). If that does not help, better ask a new question.

Answer (score 4):

You can redefine the way URLs are printed as follows (somewhere in your preamble after loading `bibtex`):

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\ifhyperref{\href{#1}{Link.}}{\url{#1}}}
```

[image: Image showing "Link"]