# Automatically add a custom url on my bibliography, based on local url rewriting

Tags: biblatex, urls, biber

I search a solution to automatically add a custom url on my bibliography, based on local url rewritting.

For example, i have a biblatex entry into `library.lib` with local pdf url like this :

```
@phdthesis{Stonedahl2011a,
author = {Stonedahl, Forrest J.},
file = {:home/srey/TRAVAUX/THESE/REPOSITORY\_PDF/RANGE/Stonedahl\_2011\_Genetic Algorithms for the Exploration of Parameter Spaces in Agent-Based Models.pdf:pdf},
number = {December},
pages = {394},
school = {Evanston, Illinois},
title = {{Genetic Algorithms for the Exploration of Parameter Spaces in Agent-Based Models}},
year = {2011}
}
```

The latex file :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,twoside, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,french=guillemets,maxlevel=3]{csquotes}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[protrusion=true]{microtype}
\sidecapmargin{outer}
\setsidecappos{t}

\usepackage[backend=biber,backref=true, natbib=true, isbn=false, doi=false, url=false, style=authoryear,maxcitenames=1, maxbibnames=999, sorting=nyt, refsection=chapter, hyperref]{biblatex}

\addbibresource[datatype=bibtex]{library.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapterstyle{bringhurst}

My blabla text with citation. \autocite{Stonedahl2011a}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

How can i add a custom url to my bibliography to download paper from a custom source and how can i translate automatically this url into biblatex file

`home/srey/TRAVAUX/THESE/REPOSITORY\_PDF/RANGE/Stonedahl\_2011\_Genetic Algorithms for the Exploration of Parameter Spaces in Agent-Based Models.pdf transform`

into

`http://mycustomserver.com/Stonedahl_2011_Genetic Algorithms for the Exploration of Parameter Spaces in Agent-Based Models.pdf`

Comment: Just one thing I noticed: `file` is a verbatim field it is therefore counter-productive to escape underscores via `\_`.

Comment: Ho :/ But the bibtex i use is an automatic file from mendeley ... thanks for notice, i search an answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `biblatex` is used with `biber` as backend, it is possible to use `\DeclareSourcemap` to perform on the fly manipulation of the fields.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=file]
      \step[fieldset=url, origfieldval]
      \step[fieldsource=url, 
        match=\regexp{:home/srey/TRAVAUX/THESE/REPOSITORY_PDF/RANGE/(.+):pdf},
        replace={http://www.example.com/$1}]
    }
  }  
}
```

The first two steps are meant to copy the value of the field `file` to the field `url`, the last `step` is to replace the path in `file` with the appropriate url.  When `\regexp` is used, normal regexp grouping and replacements are possible.

The biblatex manual describes such operations in details in section 4.5.2.

Here is the outcome (changing the `url` option to show the outcome of the substitution).

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks, I have some problem with the regex, it doesn't work on my bib, i search why .. Other question, is it possible to replace this ugly url by a text like "@download" ?

Comment: @reyman64 Since your are escaping underscores (which should not be done in `verbatim` fields such as `file`), you also need a `\step[fieldsource=url, match=\regexp{\\_}, replace=\regexp{_}]`, add that line directly after `\step[fieldset=url, origfieldval]` before `\step[fieldsource=url, match=\regexp{:home/srey/TRAVAUX/THESE/REPOSITORY_PDF/RANGE/(.+):pdf}, replace={http://www.example.com/$1}]`.

Comment: For the second part of the question you have to modify how `url` is typeset bu biblatex. A possibility  is `\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\href{#1}{Download}}`

Comment: @guido Another problem, it seems if there is also an url into bib file, it take in priority the url and not the pdf :/ How can i remove the url in this case ?

Comment: @reyman64 Try `\map[overwrite]{` instead of `\map{`. For `@download` see [It there a way to make URL link in bibliography as one word `Link`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165656/35864)

Comment: +1, if you want this to work for files other than `pdf`, maybe `\regexp{:home/srey/TRAVAUX/THESE/REPOSITORY_PDF/RANGE/(.+):\w*$}` would be slightly cooler.