# How do I replace url text with a symbol in the bibliography of a CV (moderncv class)?

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, moderncv, urls

I want to include a link to my publication, using biblatex in a CV. But instead of the whole url, I just want a symbol which can be clicked.

My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic} 

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   
\usepackage{bbding}

% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{}               
\address{somewhere}    

\email{some.thing@gmail.com}                      
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}            % hyperlinks setup
\AfterPreamble{\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{pubs.bib}
@article{cazier_whole-genome_2014,
    title = {My publication},
    volume = {5},
    url = {http://Somewebsite.html},        journal = {Nature},
    author = {Doe, John. and Smith, John},
    month = apr,
    year = {2014},
}
\end{filecontents}

\AfterPreamble{
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}
}

\usepackage[backend=biber, doi=false, isbn=false, style=nature, maxbibnames=20, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{pubs.bib}



\begin{document}
\maketitle
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={Publications}, type=article, resetnumbers=true]

\end{document}
```

What I have tried:

```
\AfterPreamble{
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}
\let\orighref\href
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{\orighref{#1}{\ArrowBoldUpRight}} %I found this code on tex.SE
}
```

What I get:
[image: result]

As you can see, I get the little arrow replacing the email link. Whereas I want the url in the bibliography replaced with the arrow, without affecting the email link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should change the anything to do with the bibliography immediately before the bibliography, otherwise it would affect everything following the preamble as in your case.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic} 

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   
\usepackage{bbding}

% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{}               
\address{somewhere}    

\email{some.thing@gmail.com}                      
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}            % hyperlinks setup
\AfterPreamble{\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{pubs.bib}
@article{cazier_whole-genome_2014,
    title = {My publication},
    volume = {5},
    url = {http://Somewebsite.html},        journal = {Nature},
    author = {Doe, John. and Smith, John},
    month = apr,
    year = {2014},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber, doi=false, isbn=false, style=nature, maxbibnames=20, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{pubs.bib}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\nocite{*}

\renewcommand{\url}[1]{\href{#1}{\ArrowBoldUpRight}}

\printbibliography[title={Publications}, type=article, resetnumbers=true]

\end{document}
```

In order to remove the surrounding `<..>`, replace `\renewcommand{\url}[1]{..}` above with

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{#1}{\ArrowBoldUpRight}}
    {\url{#1}}}
```

as suggested in [It there a way to make URL link in bibliography as one word `Link`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165656/5764).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is quite helpful. But is there a way to remove the <>? I have tried another method from here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165656/it-there-a-way-to-make-url-link-in-bibliography-as-one-word-link `\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  url = {\P},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{#1}{\bibstring{url}}}
    {\url{#1}}}` but if I replace `\P` with `\ArrowBoldUpRight` it doesn't work...