# adding asterisks to author last name using Chicago Style (meta-analysis)

Tags: biblatex, biber

Similar to [this question,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156706/functionality-of-apacites-nocitemeta-with-biblatex-apa-adding-asterisks-to-aut#new-answer?newreg=b4da373785eb48ccba858db04132d618) I would like to asterisk certain citations in the reference list but using `style=chicago-authordate` instead of `apa`. For some reason that I do not know, this small change eliminates the asterisks.  The MWE from that question is a good example here as well:

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{bohec,
  author        = {Le Bohec, Yann},
  title         = {Histoire militaire des guerres puniques},
  date          = {1996},
  location      = {Monaco},
  publisher     = {Rocher},
  isbn          = {2-268-02147-5},
}
@book{uthor,
  author        = {Uthor, Arnold},
  title         = {A Book},
  date          = {2013},
  location      = {Place},
  publisher     = {P. Ublisher's \& Co.},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{asterisk}
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \ifcategory{asterisk}%
    {*}%
    {}%
}

\begin{document}
  \addtocategory{asterisk}{uthor,bohec}
  \cite{wilde,cicero,coleridge,vangennep,bohec,uthor}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution above relies on the `begentry` bibmacro being executed in each bibliography driver as is custom with the standard styles (and I would have thought with most custom styles as well). The `biblatex-chicago` styles do not issue `begentry` at the beginning of each entry (they do use `finentry` at the end though, as do all the standard styles).

Luckily though, there is the macro `bibindex` that is executed in each `biblatex-chicago` driver.

So all we need is

```
\renewbibmacro*{bibindex}{%
  \ifbibindex
    {\indexnames{labelname}%
     \indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}
  \ifcategory{asterisk}%
    {*}%
    {}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago} 

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{bohec,
  author        = {Le Bohec, Yann},
  title         = {Histoire militaire des guerres puniques},
  date          = {1996},
  location      = {Monaco},
  publisher     = {Rocher},
  isbn          = {2-268-02147-5},
}
@book{uthor,
  author        = {Uthor, Arnold},
  title         = {A Book},
  date          = {2013},
  location      = {Place},
  publisher     = {P. Ublisher's \& Co.},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{asterisk}

\renewbibmacro*{bibindex}{%
  \ifbibindex
    {\indexnames{labelname}%
     \indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}
  \ifcategory{asterisk}%
    {*}%
    {}}


\begin{document}
  \addtocategory{asterisk}{uthor,bohec}
  \cite{wilde,cicero,coleridge,vangennep,bohec,uthor}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```