# Prepending symbols to biblatex-chicago bibliography by keyword

Tags: biblatex, biber, biblatex-chicago

Following on from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249265/adding-asterisks-to-author-last-name-using-chicago-style-meta-analysis), I would like to prepend a symbol to selected entries in my bibliography. But I would like to match the functionality [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317997/adding-symbols-to-the-beginning-of-certain-references-in-the-reference-list) where the symbol is inserted automatically based on keywords in the `.bbl` file.

I can achieve the desired output by uncommenting the two lines in the MWE which does the job manually:

[image]

It'd be much more efficient for my workflow if I could use keywords instead.

As far as I can work out, this MWE does not acknowledge the presence of `asterisk` in the `keywords` field, even though I've tried to follow the logic in the above links:

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
  bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{uthor,
  author        = {Uthor, Arnold},
  title         = {A Book},
  date          = {2013},
  location      = {Place},
  publisher     = {P. Ublisher's \& Co.},
  keywords      = {asterisk}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

%\DeclareBibliographyCategory{asterisk}

\renewbibmacro*{bibindex}{%
  \ifbibindex
    {\indexnames{labelname}%
     \indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}
  \ifcategory{asterisk}%
    {*}%
    {}%
}

\begin{document}
%  \addtocategory{asterisk}{uthor}
  \cite{uthor}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Please can someone let me know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I see is to use the `\ifkeyword` test. I prefer to use `xpatch` in similar cases:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\AtEveryBibitem{\ifkeyword{asterisk}%
 {\xapptobibmacro{bibindex}{*}{}{}}
 {}}
```

but you can also do without it if you prefer:

```
\renewbibmacro*{bibindex}{%
 \ifbibindex
 {\indexnames{labelname}%
  \indexfield{indextitle}}
 {}
\ifkeyword{asterisk}{*}{}%
}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
 @book{uthor,
  author        = {Uthor, Arnold},
  title         = {A Book},
  date          = {2013},
  location      = {Place},
  publisher     = {P. Ublisher's \& Co.},
  keywords      = {asterisk}
 }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
    
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptobibmacro{bibindex}{\ifkeyword{asterisk}{*}{}}{}{}

\begin{document}
 
 \paragraph{An entry with “asterisk” keyword}
 \cite{uthor}
 
 \paragraph{An entry without “asterisk” keyword} 
 \cite{knuth:ct}
 
 \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I follow your logic in preferring `xpatch` and will use it myself.