# Indicating corresponding author in list of publications

Tags: biblatex, cv

Is there a way to add an asterisk (or some other symbol) before or after the number in the references list when using `biblatex`?

I am creating a CV and I want to highlight the papers for which I am the corresponding author so it would look like this:

[image]

but the most I have achieved is by making the list manually:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[style=ieee,url=false,doi=false,maxbibnames=99,sorting=ydnt,dashed=false]{biblatex}

\bibliography{papers}

\usepackage{simplecv}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\corresp}{%
  \refstepcounter{\@enumctr}% step the level-specific counter
  \item[% Insert item/enumeration
    \textdagger
    \,% Space
    \@nameuse{label\@enumctr}]% Place level-formatted counter
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{Publications}

\begin{enumerate}
    \corresp First Author, Second Author, \textbf{My Name}, Other Corresponding Author, \textit{Journal}, \textbf{1991}, \textit{20}, pp. 1-3.
    \corresp First Author, Second Author, Someone Else, \textbf{Me Again}, \textit{Journal}, \textbf{1992}, \textit{30}, pp. 4-5.
    \item First Author, Second Author, Someone Else, \textbf{Not Corresponding Me}, Corresponding Author \textit{Journal}, \textbf{1993}, \textit{40}, pp. 5-6.
\end{enumerate}
\textdagger indicates applicant is (co-) corresponding author.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/317997/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103854/35864 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156706/35864 help?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to these, however they work with reference styles that do not have numbering. If I implement them, the asterisk simply goes before the first author name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same basic idea as in [Functionality of apacites \nocitemeta with biblatex-apa: adding asterisks to author lastnames (meta-analysis)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156706/35864).

We just need to print the symbol in the field format `labelnumberwidth` instead of in the `begentry` bibmacro to ensure the symbol appears before the label number.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ieee,
  sorting=ydnt,
  maxbibnames=99,
  url=false,doi=false,
  dashed=false,
]{biblatex}

\newtoggle{bib@corresponding}
\DeclareEntryOption{corresponding}[true]{\settoggle{bib@corresponding}{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{%
  \iftoggle{bib@corresponding}%
    {\textdagger}%
    {}%
  \mkbibbrackets{#1}%
}

\defbibnote{corresponding}{\textdagger\ indicates applicant is (co-) corresponding author.}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{bohec,
  author        = {Le Bohec, Yann},
  title         = {Histoire militaire des guerres puniques},
  date          = {1996},
  location      = {Monaco},
  publisher     = {Rocher},
  isbn          = {2-268-02147-5},
  options       = {corresponding},
}
@book{uthor,
  author        = {Uthor, Arnold},
  title         = {A Book},
  date          = {2013},
  location      = {Place},
  publisher     = {P. Ublisher's \& Co.},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \autocite{bohec,uthor}
  \printbibliography[postnote=corresponding]
\end{document}
```

[image: Entry marked with a dagger.]

---

Different markers can be added analogously.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ieee,
  sorting=ydnt,
  maxbibnames=99,
  url=false,doi=false,
  dashed=false,
]{biblatex}

\newtoggle{bibentry@corresponding}
\DeclareEntryOption{corresponding}[true]{\settoggle{bibentry@corresponding}{#1}}

\newtoggle{bibentry@cofirst}
\DeclareEntryOption{cofirst}[true]{\settoggle{bibentry@cofirst}{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{%
  \iftoggle{bibentry@corresponding}%
    {\textdagger}%
    {}%
  \iftoggle{bibentry@cofirst}%
    {\textdaggerdbl}%
    {}%
  \mkbibbrackets{#1}%
}

\defbibnote{corresponding}{\textdagger\ indicates applicant is (co-) corresponding author.}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{bohec,
  author        = {Le Bohec, Yann},
  title         = {Histoire militaire des guerres puniques},
  date          = {1996},
  location      = {Monaco},
  publisher     = {Rocher},
  isbn          = {2-268-02147-5},
  options       = {corresponding},
}
@book{uthor,
  author        = {Uthor, Arnold},
  title         = {A Book},
  date          = {2013},
  location      = {Place},
  publisher     = {P. Ublisher's \& Co.},
  options       = {cofirst},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \autocite{bohec,uthor}
  \printbibliography[postnote=corresponding]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! If I may get greedy, how do I go about adding a second symbol? Eg. if I wanted to indicate equal first authorships? 

I tried the following but, like I said, I don't know what I'm doing here.. :)

\newtoggle{bib@corresponding}
\DeclareEntryOption{corresponding}[true]{\settoggle{bib@corresponding}{#1}}
\newtoggle{bib@cofirst}
\DeclareEntryOption{cofirst}[true]{\settoggle{bib@cofirst}{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{%
  \iftoggle{bib@corresponding}%
    {\textdagger}%
    {\iftoggle{bib@cofirst}}
    {\textdaggerdbl}
    {}%
  \mkbibbrackets{#1}%
}

Comment: @Dim See the edit, please. (You were almost there, the combined `\iftoggle`s were just a bit off.)

Comment: Yes! Thank you!

Comment: @Dim If the answer solved your question, you may want to consider accepting it by clicking the green checkmark on the top left of the answer. That way the question is marked as resolved. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: thanks for pointing that out.. I was trying to upvote with no luck [facepalm]
:)