# Mark selected references in bibliography with an asterisk

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

is there a way to indicate/mark certain selected references in the bibliography section.
For example I want to use simple natbib citations (author-year) in the main text (standard as they are). However in my reference list (bibliography) I want mark some references (not all) with an asterisk before the main name. Here a short example, but how to add the asterisk?
Do I need to introduce a new field (eg. marker) for @article and define a new bibliography style the accounts for the new field?

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
author={Name},
journal={Journal},
title={TITLE},
year={2011},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\begin{document}
\cite{test}

\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A solution with biblatex: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103854/is-it-possible-to-mark-designated-entries-in-a-bibliography-with-an-asterisk/103862#103862

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that works with BibTeX and the `natbib` citation management package. It's admittedly quite kludgy. If someone's got a better solution, please step forward.

The solution consists of three parts. First, add the following lines to the top of the `.bib` file:

```
@preamble{ " \newcommand{\noopsort}[1]{} "
         # " \newcommand{\bibstar}{\textsuperscript{*}} " }
```

If necessary, modify the definition of `\bibstar` so that its output conforms to your needs. The macro `\noopsort` seems to do nothing but, as will become clear soon, is very useful for *sorting* purposes.

Second, for each entry that's supposed to be prefixed with a "star" in the references section, modify the (first) author's name as follows: Instead of, say,

```
author = {Henry Jones},
```

write

```
author = {Henry \noopsort{Jones}\bibstar{}Jones},
```

The instruction `\noopsort{Jones}` ensures that the entry will be sorted under "J" for "Jones" rather than under whatever BibTeX decides the sorting order may be for "`*`" (probably after "Z").

Third, for each starred entry, define a "citation alias" using the mechanism provided by `natbib`. E.g., if the entry for Henry Jones's piece has the key `jones11`, you'd write

```
\defcitealias{jones11}{Jones (2011)}
```

in the preamble (after the `natbib` package has been loaded).

With these three things put in place, use `\citetalias` rather than `\citet` to cite the entry in question, i.e., write `\citetalias{jones11}`. (If you use `\citet` you'd get, surprise, `*Jones (2011)`...)

A full example:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@preamble{ " \newcommand{\noop}[1]{} "
         # " \newcommand{\bibstar}{\textsuperscript{*}} " }
@article{jones11,
author={Henry \noop{Jones}\bibstar{}Jones},
journal={Circularity Today},
title={Deep thoughts},
year={2011},
volume = 1,
issue  = 1,
pages  = "1-101",
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\defcitealias{jones11}{Jones (2011)}
\begin{document}
\citetalias{jones11}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following method: I create a sty file called `citestar.sty`, which modifies the definition of `\cite` and `\bibitem`. And then when citing a reference that needs to be emphasized with asterisk, I cite it as `\cite{key1, key2*, key3}`. The entry for `key2` will be emphasized. The content of `citestar.sty` is as follows:

```
% Modify the behavior of \cite and \bibitem commands such that when a
% key is followed by an astarisk (star *), the bibliography entry will have a
% star on the left margin. Example: \cite{key1,key2*,key3}. This will show
% key2 entry with a star on the margin.
%
% \usepackage{citestar}
% \begin{document}

% \cite{key1,key2*,key3}

% \begin{thebibliography}{99}
% \bibitem{key1} First reference.
% \bibitem{key2} Second reference.
% \bibitem{key3} Third reference.
% \end{thebibliography}
% \end{document}

% remove spaces from a string
\def\removeSpaces#1{\expandafter\removeSpacesA#1\relax}
\def\removeSpacesA#1{%
  \ifx\relax#1\else%
    \ifx#1\ \else#1\fi%
    \expandafter\removeSpacesA%
  \fi}

% process a single bib key, check if it ends with *. If so, remembers it.
% Then, strip the *, and put the stripped key back to the list \keysWithoutAster
\newcommand{\processSingleKey}[1]{%
    \expandafter\@checkAsterisk#1*\@nil%
}

\def\@checkAsterisk#1*#2\@nil{%
    \addToCommaSeparatedList{\keysWithoutAster}{#1}%
    \ifx\relax#2\relax% does not end with *
    \else% ends with *
       \expandafter\gdef\csname key@\removeSpaces{#1}\endcsname{}%
    \fi%
}

% Define a macro to add a string to a comma-separated list
\newcommand{\addToCommaSeparatedList}[2]{%
    \edef#1{%
        \ifx#1\empty\else#1,\fi % Add comma if the list is not empty
        #2% Append the new string
    }%
}

% Define a loop macro for comma-separated lists
\newcommand{\foreachcsv}[2]{%
  \@for\tmp:=#1\do{#2{\tmp}}%
}

% Redefine \cite to remember keys with asterisks.
\let\oldcite\cite
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{%
  \def\keysWithoutAster{}% Clear oldkeys
  \foreachcsv{#1}{\processSingleKey}%
  \expandafter\oldcite\expandafter{\keysWithoutAster}%
}%

% Redefine \bibitem to add an asterisk to labels of remembered keys
\let\oldbibitem\bibitem
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[1]{%
    \ifcsname key@\removeSpaces{#1}\endcsname%
      \oldbibitem{#1}%
        \makebox[0pt][r]{\bfseries*\hspace*{2em}}%
        \hspace*{-7.3pt}
    \else%
        \oldbibitem{#1}%
    \fi%
}
```

I am sure the code can be improved. In particular, how the asterisk is placed. I didn't know how to place it on the left side without disturbing the spacing after. So I added ad hoc space of `-7.3pt`, which seems to work.