# BibTeX: Highlight selected references with asterisk (or special symbol)

Tags: bibtex

I have a tex file and a bib file and want to highlight one of the two references with an asterisk (*) *but* I do not want to use `\bibitem`. Instead I want to incorporate it with an existing bibliography format that is provided by Springer (`splncs.bst` in my case).

so, the following bibliography should change looking like this:

> [1] Adam, A., Boodle, B.: Some Title. In: Some Proceedings Book, Boston, USA, ACM (2014) 10-19
>
> [2] Boodle, B., Cool, C.: Some Other Title. Journal of Something 4 (2014) 47-62

to look like this:

> [*1] Adam, A., Boodle, B.: Some Title. In: Some Proceedings Book, Boston, USA, ACM (2014) 10-19
>
> [2] Boodle, B., Cool, C.: Some Other Title. Journal of Something 4 (2014) 47-62

Is this possible?

Here a minimal example:

The `example.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a document. 
\nocite{A,B}
\bibliographystyle{splncs} 
\bibliography{example}
\end{document}
```

The example.bib file:

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{A,
  author = {A. Adam and B. Boodle},
  title = {{Some Title}},
  booktitle = {Some Proceedings Book},
  year = {2014},
  pages = {10-19},
  address = {Boston, USA},
  publisher = {ACM}
}

@ARTICLE{B,
  author = {B. Boodle and C. Cool},
  title = {{Some Other Title}},
  journal = {Journal of Something},
  year = {2014},
  volume = {4},
  pages = {47-62},
  number = {1}
}
```

Comment: How do we know which references should have the asterisk? By the way it is very simple to achieve in `biblatex` (see, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103854/is-it-possible-to-mark-designated-entries-in-a-bibliography-with-an-asterisk/103862#103862 if `biblatex` is an option).

Comment: *You* should delete [the duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27510400/914686) since you posted it. And you're not being punished, just guided into the way things work here. Cross-posting (without just cause) should be avoided.