Add a maker next to certain citations
When I cite a reference using \cite{article}, I get some number like [3], is there a way to add a marker to certain citations so that I get, for example, [3*]?
A MWE that illustrate my case
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@book{key2,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2010},
  title = {Second Title},
  publisher = {Second Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{key}

\cite[Theorem 1]{key}

%\cite*{key}  % Outputs [1*]
%\cite*[Theorem 1]{key}  % Outputs [1*, Theorem 1]

% OR

%\cite{key*}  % Outputs [1*]
%\cite{key, key2*}  % Outputs [1, 2*]

\printbibliography

\end{document}

EDIT: I realized that I also need something like \cite{key1, key2*} which would output [1,2*], though I recognize that this might be a much more difficult command to define.

What is the idea here? Do you want to add the star only locally (i.e. only for one instance of \cite) or do you want to have the star for all citations of the same work? (The latter would be easy: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/249775/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439576/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/645694/35864. The former would be trickier - especially with the interface you propose.)

Either one would work for me. Thanks for the links, they have exactly what i need.

Nice. Would you be OK with us closing this question as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439576/35864 then?
