# Getting starred entries in BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I can't get the solution to work from this previous question and answer: [Is it possible to mark designated entries in a bibliography with an asterisk?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103854/is-it-possible-to-mark-designated-entries-in-a-bibliography-with-an-asterisk)

Here is my example code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sorting=none, backend=biber]{biblatex} % load the package
\addbibresource{bibfilename.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
  \DeclareBibliographyCategory{asterisk} 
\end{filecontents}

\addtocategory{asterisk}{key1, key2}
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\ifcategory{asterisk}{*\addspace}{}}

\begin{document}
\cite{key1}
\bibliography{bibfilename.bib}
\end{document}
```

And I get this error message:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could  you post a .bib file?

Answer (score 1):

Use it this way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex} % load the package
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{asterisk}
\addbibresource{bibfilename.bib}

\addtocategory{asterisk}{key1, key2}
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\ifcategory{asterisk}{*\addspace}{}}

\begin{document}
\cite{key1}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The datamodel config file `biblatex-dm.cfg` is read before `biblatex` defines all its macros. As an alternative use the default config file `biblatex.cfg`

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}% allows overwriting
\begin{filecontents*}{biblatex.cfg}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{asterisk}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex} % load the package
\addbibresource{bibfilename.bib}

\addtocategory{asterisk}{key1, key2}
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\ifcategory{asterisk}{*\addspace}{}}

\begin{document}
\cite{key1}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

That file is read *after* loading `biblatex`