# Add a asterisk next to certain bib entries based on a keyword

Tags: bibtex

I am trying to add an asterisk based on a keyword/tag. I found a way to do it via citation keys ([Is it possible to mark designated entries in a bibliography with an asterisk?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103854/is-it-possible-to-mark-designated-entries-in-a-bibliography-with-an-asterisk)) but want to know if it's possible to do it with a keyword instead.