# Is there a way to highlight specific entries in a bibliography-publist with an asterisk based a keyword?

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-publist

I'd like to know if one can highlight certain bibliography entries with an asterisk to indicate the presence of some keyword (for example, invited versus uninvited entries in a CV).  I'm preparing an academic CV for promotion and I'd like a coherent unified style in the list of various activities to indicate invited versus uninvited work.

I see some solutions, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103854/is-it-possible-to-mark-designated-entries-in-a-bibliography-with-an-asterisk), but they won't work for me as I'm using Zotero to create my .bib file, so I can't go through and add an asterisk field to a bunch of entries.  Thank you.,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=publist]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  keyword={peerreviewed}
}

@misc{key2,
  author = {Author, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Title2},
  keywords={guestlecture, invited}
}

@misc{key3,
  author = {Author, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Title3},
  keywords={guestlecture}
 
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[title={Books}, type={book}]

\printbibliography[title={Guest Lectures}, type={misc}, keyword={guestlecture}, notkeyword={invited}]

\printbibliography[title={Guest Lectures}, type={misc}, keyword={guestlecture}, keyword={invited}]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the modification to go on the numeric label of your bibliography, you can do so by modifying the printing of `labelnumber` to depend on whether the `invited` keyword is present.

For MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  keyword={peerreviewed}
}

@misc{key2,
  author = {Author, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Title2},
  keywords={guestlecture, invited}
}

@misc{key3,
  author = {Author, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Title3},
  keywords={guestlecture}
 
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=publist]{biblatex}

% Relevant line below
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\ifkeyword{invited}{*#1}{#1}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[title={Books}, type={book}]

\printbibliography[title={Guest Lectures}, type={misc}, keyword={guestlecture}, notkeyword={invited}]

\printbibliography[title={Guest Lectures}, type={misc}, keyword={guestlecture}, keyword={invited}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The accepted answer of your linked question can also be modified to use the `invited` keyword instead. MWE (with the same `\jobname.bib` as above, so to save space I omit it):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=publist]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro{begentry}{%
  \ifkeyword{invited}
    {*\addspace}
    {}%
}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[title={Books}, type={book}]

\printbibliography[title={Guest Lectures}, type={misc}, keyword={guestlecture}, notkeyword={invited}]

\printbibliography[title={Guest Lectures}, type={misc}, keyword={guestlecture}, keyword={invited}]

\end{document}
```

This places the asterisk as the first character of the entry.

[image]